# Old British black-and-white humorous ghost movie, with surprise ending

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost, humor

Saw this only once on late night television, many years ago. Looked liked it was shot in 1930s or 1940s, shot in black and white, as I recall. It was set in the British Isles about a castle/mansion and a comical group of townspeople who needed to pretend it was haunted, I think to attract tourists or maybe frighten away somebody. So they dressed up, acted out the parts, had some simple special effects, etc.

> At the very end their subterfuge worked, or wasn't needed.  Then another character shows up, dressed up as a knight. He is taunted for coming late, then walks through a wall. The townspeople scatter. Turns out the place was really haunted.

Lots of fun - great characterizations. Not the Canterville Ghost or High Spirits. I have searched various databases and used different combinations of possible keywords. The same wrong answers keep coming up. Definitely had a rural British Isles feel.

Comment: This was actually on TNT television about three or four months ago.  I don't know if the back-programming is available but will check.

Comment: Thank you! TNT is notorious for capturing and "hiding" classic movies, meaning they don't show up anywhere else to. If I find it there, make sure to make it a formal answer so you get the credit!

Comment: @johnHunt - I don't suppose you recall any more details - like was it English, Scottish, or Irish? Any recognizable actors? More about the plot. I am grateful. Thanks again. All clues appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before offering a bounty, I decided to hunker down and search a list of comedy ghost movies on IMDB, sorted by date. 1962 titles. It was #167 on the list sorted by year of release.

From Wikipedia: *Happy Ever After* is a 1954 British comedy film directed by Mario Zampi and starring David Niven, Yvonne De Carlo, Barry Fitzgerald and George Cole. Its plot concerns the accidental death of an Irish landowner who bequeaths his estate to his cousin. It was released in the United States under the title *Tonight's the Night.*

I looked at several descriptions before I found one that hinted at the surprise ending. So I am 99% sure this is the one. Now will hunt up a DVD in a format I can watch.

Comment: I've looked at some of it on YouTube....it wasn't black and white!

Comment: Yep, just my old-fashioned brain.